# Player cant take stairs

Tags: javascript, three.js

im trying to get a player move around the house, i was successful in loading the house with obj and mtl loaders and installing the player(he is able to move front and back) , however the problem is he can't take stairs down or up. I have used point_lock_controles and raycaster in my code please let me know where i went wrong.

```
controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera );
                scene.add( controls.getObject() );
                var onKeyDown = function ( event ) {
                    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
                        case 38: //up
                        case 87: //w
                            moveForward = true;
                            break;
                        case 37: //left
                        case 65: //a
                            moveLeft = true; break;
                        case 40: //down
                        case 83: //s
                            moveBackward = true;
                            break;
                        case 39: //right
                        case 68: //d
                            moveRight = true;
                            break;
                        case 32: //space
                            if ( canJump === true ) velocity.y += 350;
                            canJump = false;
                            break;
                    }
                };
                var onKeyUp = function ( event ) {
                    switch( event.keyCode ) {
                        case 38: //up
                        case 87: //w
                            moveForward = false;
                            break;
                        case 37: //left
                        case 65: //a
                            moveLeft = false;
                            break;
                        case 40: //down
                        case 83: //s
                            moveBackward = false;
                            break;
                        case 39: //right
                        case 68: //d
                            moveRight = false;
                            break;
                    }
                };
                document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );
                raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ), 0, 10 );

function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                if ( controlsEnabled ) {
                    raycaster.ray.origin.copy( controls.getObject().position );
                    raycaster.ray.origin.y -= 10;
                    var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
                    var isOnObject = intersections.length > 0;
                    var time = performance.now();
                    var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;
                    velocity.x -= velocity.x * 5.0 * delta;
                    velocity.z -= velocity.z * 5.0 * delta;
                    velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass
                    if ( moveForward ) velocity.z -= 1000.0 * delta;
                    if ( moveBackward ) velocity.z += 1000.0 * delta;
                    if ( moveLeft ) velocity.x -= 1000.0 * delta;
                    if ( moveRight ) velocity.x += 1000.0 * delta;
                    if ( isOnObject === true ) {
                        velocity.y = Math.max( 0, velocity.y );
                        canJump = true;
                    }
                    controls.getObject().translateX( velocity.x * delta );
                    controls.getObject().translateY( velocity.y * delta );
                    controls.getObject().translateZ( velocity.z * delta );
                    if ( controls.getObject().position.y < 10 ) {
                        velocity.y = 0;
                        controls.getObject().position.y = 10;
                        canJump = true;
                    }
                    prevTime = time;
                }
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Guys, i tried using the example FPS https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_fps.html

since this example uses json loader, the parameters passed to applyphysics() function are different. However, i use OBJ and MTL loader, tried to change a bit and could get the model loaded but not able to get any movement like in the example, the player keeps faling down and it shows " three.js:8786 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D." something wrong with my code refernce. Please help me out

My question is "How to add obj + mtl loader into this example and load my model with movement " This below code is the only code i manually inserted into this example, https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_fps.html

```
function makePlatform() {
                var placeholder = new THREE.Object3D();
                var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                    }
                };

                var onError = function ( xhr ) { };

                THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
                var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'myhouse/' );
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'myhouse/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'house.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();

                var platform = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    platform.setMaterials( materials );
                    platform.setPath( 'myhouse/' );
                    platform.load( 'house.obj', function ( object ) {
                        object.position.y = - 95;
                        object.castShadow = true;
                        object.receiveShadow = true;
                        object.traverse( function( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { node.castShadow = true;
                                       node.receiveShadow = true; } } );
                    scene.add( object );
                    object.name="platform";
                    placeholder.add(platform);
                    },onProgress, onError );
                return placeholder;
            });
            }

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias : true });
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, 1, 0.1, 9000 );
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add( camera );
            var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75 );
            light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 0.75 );
            scene.add( light );
            scene.add( makeSkybox( [
                'skybox/px.jpg', // right
                'skybox/nx.jpg', // left
                'skybox/py.jpg', // top
                'skybox/ny.jpg', // bottom
                'skybox/pz.jpg', // back
                'skybox/nz.jpg'  // front
            ], 8000 ));
            scene.add( makePlatform());
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving on stairs is more complicated than just on a flat surface because of step levels.

Prepare navigation-mesh instead of stairs to detect ground height smoothly.

> [image]
>
> by http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-NavigationSystem.html

You may also need to understand physics things to detect collision with walls and others, like [cannon.js](http://www.cannonjs.org/) or [ammo.js](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/).

Comment: in Three.js i need exact movement like this example FPS https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_fps.html

Comment: As you can see, [the example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_fps) you shared is also using slopes instead of stairs. The down ray needs detect ground level gradually. I have tried to make [similar thing](https://yomotsu.github.io/walkthrough) with three.js too ^^

Comment: Another solution is just pull up `raycaster.ray.origin.y` higher than stair step height.

Comment: Thanks for the reply yomotsu, my current situation is the user is not able to stand on the floor, i have placed my user in balcony. since i used gravity the player keeps going down and once i take off gravity he stays stuck.
my code https://jsfiddle.net/andyram/d11bytde/